# add Authorization token using Feign client

Tags: java, spring, jwt, jhipster, feign

I have two service connected to a registry, one of them need to query some data from the other, the token need to be passed to the endpoint.

I Have tried the following but it didn't work, the endpoint act as if no token is provided.

```
    @GetMapping("/api/users/find")
    @Headers("Authorization: Bearer {token}")
    Optional<UserDTO> findUserByEmail(
        @Param("token") String token, @RequestParam("email") String email);
```

```
    @GetMapping("/api/users/find")
    Optional<UserDTO> findUserByEmail(
        @RequestHeaders("Authorization") String token, @RequestParam("email") String email);
```

```
    @GetMapping("/api/users/find")
    Optional<UserDTO> findUserByEmail(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, Object> headers , @RequestParam("email") String email);
```

Comment: Your title talks about FeignClient but you show only code from server. Why did you modify the code of the receiver endpoint, the default security configuration from JHipster  should require a JWT, no change needed; Only the caller should be changed. How do you retrieve the token in caller, with `SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserJWT()` ? Did you test your endpoint with swagger  or curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work like this `@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization`, but make sure you pass the right value, must be something like `Bearer token`.

Answer (score 1):

Your this code is absolutely correct.

```
    @GetMapping("/api/users/find")
    Optional<UserDTO> findUserByEmail(
    @RequestHeaders("Authorization") String token, @RequestParam("email") String email);
```

Just when you are calling this particular method add "Bearer " in front of the value of the token

```
token = "Bearer " + token;
findUserByEmail(token,email);
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

Create Header like this and pass to your feign client

```
private HttpHeaders getHeaders(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("authorization", httpServletRequest.getHeader("authorization"));
        return headers;
```

[Example 1](https://github.com/DeepuGeorgeJacob1/school-management/blob/main/docs/FeignClientJDBCUserSecurityS1.md)

Or very simple add intercepter

```
@Component
public class AuthFeignInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        final RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (requestAttributes != null) {
            final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
            template.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
        }
    }
}
```

[Example 2](https://github.com/DeepuGeorgeJacob1/school-management/blob/main/docs/FeignClientJDBCUserSecurityS2.md)